# How to restore a single subfolder to specific date without affecting others using Git?

Tags: git, version-control, restore

I have a Git repository which includes a whole folder structure, and I want o reset *one of them* (not all) to the state it was in *at a particular time*, but I do not want to affect any of the other files/folders of the repository.

How do I achive this with Git?

Say I have Git repository in my `root/` folder that contains:

```
root/
root/FolderA/
root/FolderB/sub1/
root/FolderB/sub2/
root/FolderC/
```

I want to restore `root/FolderB/` and all of its contents to the situation it was on 1st January 2018, but I do not want to change the content of the other folders.

Note, I'm generally using a UI frontent ([Git Extensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions)), so I'm not regularly using GIT from a command line. Neither am I very proficient in GIT in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will restore the version of `root/FolderB/` from the last commit before the 2nd of January 2018:

```
git checkout $(git rev-list -n 1 --before="2018-01-02 00:00" master)^ -- root/FolderB/
```

**Explanation:**

- `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2018-01-02 00:00" master`: get the hash of the last commit before the 2nd of January 2018
- `git checkout <commit-hash>^ master -- root/FolderB/`: restore the `root/FolderB/` from `<commit-hash>` on the `master` branch